# JAVA Round to closest number

Tags: java, math

How to round a decimal number to closest "whole" number?

Comment: @RahulV.Mane although one can figure the answer to my question from the thread you proposed, this is not the same question, and not the same answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using

```
float x = (float)Math.ceil(x);
```

or

```
float y = (float)Math.round(y);
```

Also note that I have converted them back to float as there may be a loss of precision when you are converting double to float.

Comment: why float and not double?

Comment: @Alaychem:- You can take double as well. Same logic. I picked float!

Comment: This does not quite work, but it gets the idea across. `float x = (float)Math.ceil(x);` declares a new variable and then try to use the undefined value of that variable to assign a value to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

One line answer!

```
 public static long roundToClosestLong(long num, long div) {
         return (long) num / div + ((double) (num % div) / div < 0.5 ? 0 : 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.lang.Math` class for that.

1. [Math#round(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) Will accecpt `double` as argument and returns `long`
2. [Math#round(float)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)) Will accecpt `float` as argument and returns `int`

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
int result = (int) (yourValue + 0.5);
```

if you just need simple rounding this is maybe a more performant solution than `Math.round(yourValue)`